# Applying IndexToString to features vector in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

**Context:** I have a data frame where all categorical values have been indexed using StringIndexer.

```
val categoricalColumns = df.schema.collect { case StructField(name, StringType, nullable, meta) => name }    

val categoryIndexers = categoricalColumns.map {
  col => new StringIndexer().setInputCol(col).setOutputCol(s"${col}Indexed") 
}
```

Then I used VectorAssembler to vectorize all feature columns (including the indexed categorical ones).

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(dfIndexed.columns.diff(List("label") ++ categoricalColumns))
    .setOutputCol("features")
```

After applying the classifier and a few additional steps I end up with a data frame that has label, features, and prediction. I would like expand my features vector to separate columns in order to convert the indexed values back to their original String form.

```
val categoryConverters = categoricalColumns.zip(categoryIndexers).map {
colAndIndexer => new IndexToString().setInputCol(s"${colAndIndexer._1}Indexed").setOutputCol(colAndIndexer._1).setLabels(colAndIndexer._2.fit(df).labels)
}
```

**Question:** Is there a *simple* way of doing this, or is the best approach to somehow attach the prediction column to the test data frame?

**What I have tried:**

```
val featureSlicers = categoricalColumns.map {
  col => new VectorSlicer().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol(s"${col}Indexed").setNames(Array(s"${col}Indexed"))
}
```

Applying this gives me the columns that I want, but they are in Vector form (as it is meant to do) and not type Double.

**Edit:**
The desired output is the original data frame (i.e. categorical features as String not index) with an additional column indicating the predicted label (which in my case is 0 or 1).

For example, say the output of my classifier looked something like this:

```
+-----+---------+----------+
|label| features|prediction|
+-----+---------+----------+
|  1.0|[0.0,3.0]|       1.0|
+-----+---------+----------+
```

By applying VectorSlicer on each feature I would get:

```
+-----+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|label| features|prediction|statusIndexed|artistIndexed|
+-----+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  1.0|[0.0,3.0]|       1.0|        [0.0]|        [3.0]|
+-----+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Which is great, but I need:

```
+-----+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|label| features|prediction|statusIndexed|artistIndexed|
+-----+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  1.0|[0.0,3.0]|       1.0|         0.0 |         3.0 |
+-----+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

To then be able to use IndexToString and convert it to:

```
+-----+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|label| features|prediction|    status   |    artist   |
+-----+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  1.0|[0.0,3.0]|       1.0|        good |  Pink Floyd |
+-----+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

or even:

```
+-----+----------+-------------+-------------+
|label|prediction|    status   |    artist   |
+-----+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  1.0|       1.0|        good |  Pink Floyd |
+-----+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have a dataset of thousands or columns and some of them are categorical so I must "split" them into more columns using a `StringIndexer` and `OneHotEncoder`. The problem comes when I try to realize what represents every feature of the combined vector.

Comment: Is there any reason to drop input data in the first place?

Comment: Yes. The classification algo expects a data frame with a "label" and "feature" column. Where the feature column is a Vector an cannot have Strings. To be clear, I still have the original data frame with all the input data.

Comment: If you have original data why extract this information from there instead of vector? I mean it is possible with a small UDF by why bother?

Comment: Curiosity, mostly. Also, appending a column from one dataframe to another does not seem as straightforward as I expected.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Partial code in the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is not a very useful operation but it should be possible to extract required information using column metadata and as simple UDF. I assume your data has been created a pipeline similar to this one:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{VectorSlicer, VectorAssembler, StringIndexer}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1L, "a", "foo", 1.0), (2L, "b", "bar", 2.0), (3L, "a", "bar", 3.0)
)).toDF("id", "x1", "x2", "x3")

val featureCols = Array("x1", "x2", "x3")
val featureColsIdx = featureCols.map(c => s"${c}_i")

val indexers = featureCols.map(
  c => new StringIndexer().setInputCol(c).setOutputCol(s"${c}_i")
)

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(featureColsIdx)
  .setOutputCol("features")

val slicer = new VectorSlicer()
  .setInputCol("features")
  .setOutputCol("string_features")
  .setNames(featureColsIdx.init)


val transformed = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(indexers :+ assembler :+ slicer)
  .fit(df)
  .transform(df)
```

First we can extract desired metadata from the features:

```
val meta = transformed.select($"string_features")
  .schema.fields.head.metadata
  .getMetadata("ml_attr") 
  .getMetadata("attrs")
  .getMetadataArray("nominal")
```

and convert it to something easier to use

```
case class NominalMetadataWrapper(idx: Long, name: String, vals: Array[String])

// In general it could a good idea to make it a broadcast variable
val lookup = meta.map(m => NominalMetadataWrapper(
  m.getLong("idx"), m.getString("name"), m.getStringArray("vals")
))
```

Finally a small UDF:

```
import scala.util.Try

val transFeatures = udf((v: Vector) => lookup.map{
  m => Try(m.vals(v(m.idx.toInt).toInt)).toOption
})

transformed.select(transFeatures($"string_features")).
```

Comment: Thanks! Although it is not the most useful operation it is helpful to know how to do this.

Comment: Truth be told I've answered out of curiosity :-)

Comment: Hi @zero323 I tried the code that you gave in your answer, but the feature names that I get are mixed with the feature values as well? For example, if I have a feature 'vendor' with indexed name as "vendor_ml_input" and values as "microsoft", "dell" etc, I get the feature names as "vendor_ml_input_microsoft" and "vendor_ml_input_dell", any suggesstions on how do I get the feature names?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I had OneHotEncoder in the VectorAssembly chain, once I removed it, this worked as you said. Thanks