# Create an Array from features vector in Apache Spark/ Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to create an array of all the features in a features Vector in Apache Spark and scala. I need to do this in order to create a Breeze Matrix of the features for various commputations in my algorithm. Currently the features are wrapped in a features vector and I want to extract each of these separately. I've been looking at the following question:
[Applying IndexToString to features vector in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435434/applying-indextostring-to-features-vector-in-spark)

Here's my current code: (data is a Spark DataFrame, all features are Doubles)

```
val featureCols = Array("feature1", "feature2", "feature3") 
val featureAssembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(featureCols).setOutputCol("features")
val dataWithFeatures = featureAssembler.transform(data)

//now we slice the features back again
val featureSlicer = featureCols.map {
  col => new VectorSlicer().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol(s"${col}_sliced").setNames(Array(s"${col}"))}
val output = featureSlicer.map(f => f.transform(dataWithFeatures).select(f.getOutputCol).as[Double].collect)
val array = output.flatten.toArray
```

However this fails with the following error: 'cannot resolve CAST("feature1" AS DOUBLE due to data type mismatch - cannot cast VectorUDT to DoubleType'

This seems odd since I can do the following without an error:

`val array: Array[Double] = dataWithFeatures.select("feature1").as[Double].collect()`

Any ideas how to fix this, and if there is a better way, as it seems inefficient to create a sequence of DataFrames and perform the operation on each one separately.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you need as result? `Array[Array[Double]]`?

Comment: Ideally just Array[Double]. As underlying a BreezeDM is just an array of values. But I can flatten Array[Array[Double]] if necessary I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say if `features` column is the `vector` column that gets assembled from all the other features column, you can select the `features` column, convert it to `rdd` and then `flatMap` it:

*Example data*:

```
dataWithFeatures.show
+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
|feature1|feature2|feature3|     features|
+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
|       1|       2|       3|[1.0,2.0,3.0]|
|       4|       5|       6|[4.0,5.0,6.0]|
+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

---

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

dataWithFeatures.select("features").rdd.flatMap(r => r.getAs[Vector](0).toArray).collect
// res19: Array[Double] = Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0)
```

Comment: Wow! That's amazing - very quick, very neat - I have been wrestling with this for four hours! Thank you!

Comment: PS. How do you format your tables like that in the answer please?

Comment: Do you mean the *Example data*? You can simply format it as code by selecting the table and then `edit` -> `{}`.

Comment: I now have the same problem with the label column, which is simply a column of doubles. This doesn't work: `val array = ds.select("label").rdd.flatMap(r => r.getAs[Double].toArray).collect`. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you try your own method(the last line of code in OP) with it? It should work for a column of doubles. or `ds.select("label").rdd.map(r => r.getAs[Double](0)).collect` you don't need `flatMap` and `toArray` as it's a double not a vector.

Comment: Do you mean: `ds.select("label").as[Double].collect() - yes that works, thanks!